# Are there examples of businesses that profit from helping consumers coordinate better?

Tags: government, cooperative-game-theory, market-failure

In economics, its often assumed that individuals are unable to coordinate. Moreover, its often assumed that one of the roles for the government is to help consumers coordinate. However, its also possible that businesses that find a way to help consumers coordinate could fulfill that role. 
Are there examples of businesses dedicated to and profiting from helping consumers coordinate better?

Comment: By coordinating you mean "acting in each others interest". If so Uber seems a good example, what do you think ?

Comment: If my understanding of your question is correct, websites like Angie's List would be prime examples of this.

Comment: It seems to me that Uber and Angie's are about market efficiency.  I'm thinking something like those  websites that help people create a flashmob that storms a store and demands discounts from the manager. That particular example seems like bullying but the idea is that there are things that only work if many people do them together. For example: Suppose I'm moving to a different city. I would love a website that lets me coordinate with many other family with same age kids that is moving to the same city, to agree that we'll all move to the same neighborhood, thus creating a great community.